# Getting the Phone Country Code from users phone number in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, locale

Hi I have an IOS application in which the user can use Digists to authenticate.

When you authenticate with Digists you get an String value of the phone number.

I would like to know if there is any way I can find out the Locale/phone code of the user using this phone number string.

**For example:**
Lets say the user has some French sim card number and goes to Great Britain. Then he uses Digits to authenticate in our app.

Lets assume his phone number is +33509758351. Is there a way to find out that the phone code for the phone number +33509758351 is +33 or find out that the Local for that phone number is FR?

I know there are libraries like [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) which can be used to validate a phone number against a locale, but I cannot seem to find one that will give me the user's Locale/Phone Code based on phone number string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
let phone : String = "your phone with carrier region"
let phonUtil = NBPhoneNumberUtil()
do {
    let nbPhone : NBPhoneNumber = try phonUtil.parse(withPhoneCarrierRegion: phone)
    var countryCode : NSNumber = phoneStep1.countryCode
}catch{
    //Phone Number Invalid!
}
```